# further VS. more

Tags: word-choice

> Please, would you give me some **further** coffee?

vs.

> Please, would you give me some **more** coffee?

Could you think of when and/or where we could use *further*  meaning **more**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm only considering the interchangeability of further and more here, other meanings of further are no taken into account.)

1. Use "further" when you want to express some range or degree, either physically or metaphorically. 
   Examples:

   - further research: include new aspects, new methods, new data....
   - further down the road: from your position, extend down the road.
2. *Only* "more" is correct, when you focus on a measurable amount, even with uncountable nouns. 
   Examples:

   - more shoes
   - more coffee
   - more reputation on Stack Exchange
     Example in one sentence:
   - We need more money for further research.
3. On interchangeability:
   When *both* extension and countability are correct, you can use "more" instead of further, but usually "further" sounds more polished.
   Example:

   - We need more research. / We need further research.
   - Move a few inches more to the right. / Move a few inches further to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Further is more commonly used as an adverb relating to the degree of something.

> It is located further to the right than I thought.

Further can be used in some contexts to mean "more" or "additional"

> Further meetings on this topic seem pointless
>
> Further research is needed to reach a decision

Further cannot in this sense replace more or additional in general.

Comment: So, "futher" in the adjective role seems to combine better with nouns describing an action (meeting, research) rather than designating some object or substance (cofee, sugar cubes).

Comment: So, when/ where could they be interchangeable?

Comment: More research / further research. You may use "more" instead of "further", but then further is usually the better choice. You can't use "further" when "more" is referring to an "amount".

Comment: I think a general rule is hard to define. Further in general relates to degree, so it can be used with nouns related to extended processes (study, research, debate) or series of things (meeting, testing, discussion(s), etc).
I don't think it can be correctly used with physical items (like food)